# Firebase function using Typescript nested promise

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create an API for my Firebase project using functions. The difficult part is that I am using TypeScript and I keep running into typing problems.

This is my sign up route:

```
app.post('/signup', (req: Request, res: Response) =>{
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle
  }
  // TODO: validate data
  db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).get()
    .then( doc => {
      // Duplicated handle
      if(doc.exists){
        return res.status(400).json({ handle: 'this handle is already taken'});
      }
      // Valid handle
      else {
        return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password); 
      }
    })
    .then( data => {
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then( token => {
      return res.status(201).json({ token });
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code })
    });
})
```

Errors:

1. The doc in the first has the following error

> Argument of type '(doc: DocumentSnapshot) =>
>   Response | Promise' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(value: DocumentSnapshot) =>
>   UserCredential | PromiseLike'.

This is because I am returning a response status if the handle already exists, to avoid duplicates. From my understanding, this would go to the catch; and the valid handle would return a Promise that the next then would take. However, this is not working

2. data.user.getIdToken() says that

> Property 'user' does not exist on type
>   'DocumentSnapshot'.
>   Tried delcaring a const for user before using it, but get the same message.

I have other functions for post and get from firestore working, but can't get the authentication ones to work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested your code but both your problems most probably come from the fact that you are calling `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` and `getIdToken()`, which are methods of the [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js?authuser=0).

In a Cloud function, you need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node?authuser=0), and therefore call the [`createuser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth?authuser=0#createuser) method.

```
  db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).get()
    .then( doc => {
      // Duplicated handle
      if(doc.exists){
        return res.status(400).json({ handle: 'this handle is already taken'});
      }
      // Valid handle
      else {
        return admin.auth().createUser(newUser.email, newUser.password); 
      }
    })
    .then(userRecord => {
      //... see below 
    })
```

Note that we replace `firebase` by `admin`, in order to use the Admin SDK. Don't forget to initialize it with `const admin = require('firebase-admin'); admin.initializeApp();`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app.

Then, you are using `getIdToken()` which is, again, a method from the JavaScript SDK.

You need to adapt your code depending on what was your exact goal by sending back a token to the front-end.

If you want to login the user in the front-end, just send back the info that the user was successfully created, and, in the front-end, call the [`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?authuser=0#signinwithemailandpassword) method.

---

Finally note two other important points:

1. You should use a [Transaction](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html) to check that the user doc is not existing
2. The `db` variable shall be declared as `admin.firestore()`.

Comment: createUser(newUser.email, newUser.password) does not exist on type auth, so that didn't help. I'll try to look more into Admin SDK documentation. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake from my side: I didn't replace all what needed to be replaced... you need to do `admin.auth().createUser(newUser.email, newUser.password);` instead of `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password);`. Note that we replace `firebase` by `admin`, to use the Admin SDK. Don't forget to initialize with `const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();`